# Want to keep user grade data of course but remove his student role when his enrollment duration is expired

Tags: moodle

I Want to keep user grade data of course but remove his student role when his enrollment duration is expired. is there anyway to do it I did not find any option like this in the enrollment plugins.

can anyone help me to short out this.

Comment: What version of Moodle are you using? What type of enrolment plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The option was added in Moodle 2.4. Source: [Add setting for cron action after enrolment expiration - enrol_manual](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-35063).

Path: *Site administration » Plugins » Enrolments » Manual enrolments*. 
Select the option *Disable course enrolment and remove roles* in *Enrolment expiration action*.